# How to avoid a second ban on English Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion, reputation, banned

A while back, I was blocked from asking questions on the English Stack Exchange, which struck me by surprise. Having never been banned from a site on the Internet before, this was new to me. On the English Stack Exchange, I would often ask questions related to issues I'd think of while editing a book. Based on the information from https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask, my guess is that my questions were too specific to what I was editing to be useful for everyone. I'd like to return to the site, now as a useful member.

From here on, what can I do to avoid getting blocked a second time? Once I make my next post, will my reputation on the site determine whether I'll be able to continue posting afterward?

Comment: You’ve already asked a few questions which are valid for this site. What was the reason for being blocked?

Comment: @user66974 I'm not sure. I believe it said that my questions weren't being well-received. When I got blocked, I didn't see it coming at all. Is there usually a warning or something? The whole thing's confusing to me, but there are probably things I can do to improve, I'd assume. I believe they also said that while I can post another question six months after being blocked, I would have to wait yet another six months before posting afterward unless the question helped my reputation a lot. Does that sound accurate?

Comment: I'll bet you have deleted questions that weren't well received. You may be able to find the recent ones, otherwise a diamond mod would have to check. See [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997/323179) for more information on the ban.

Comment: @Laurel I planned to delete them, but I forget if I actually went through with it. I was informed that deleting questions won't make the negative marks go away, so I may have kept them. I'm not sure.

Comment: There certainly is an automated warning, and it can be shown more than once. From your comments here, I guess you have seen the [generic advice on question bans](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th). We can't do "cross-site" duplicates, but is there anything in the answer there which you cannot apply to your posts or post history? (If there is, edit your question here to be explicit and detailed.)

Comment: @AndrewLeach Strangely, I don't remember seeing a warning. I've read the link before but now noticed this: "The only way for the ban to be lifted is by contributing positively to the site in other ways." While I now can contribute to the site by asking questions since the block has been lifted, would contributing in other ways be advisable first? Also, if I post another question on the English Stack Exchange, will I automatically be blocked again for 6 months, or is that unlikely? I could edit my question to just ask that. Is this a good idea, or would it change the question too significantly?

Comment: I was in a similar position on web apps stack exchange. I never figured out why it happened, but I had placed at least 1-2 bounties while I was already on low rep (~200). So I figured the rep lost from bounties may have triggered (or *mistakenly* triggered) some automated process. Not totally sure though.

Comment: We’re you blocked on this account, “the editor”? If you were blocked on another account, provide  us a URL to that account (the name alone won’t help), and we may be able to diagnose any issues you had with your questions.

Comment: @DanBron The account was this one, The Editor. Does it seem that nothing currently appears iffy on my account as it currently stands?

Comment: @TheEditor A quick review of your posts doesn’t show anything off, so far as I can see. You don’t have any negative-scoring posts. The only explanation I can offer is what others have suggested: you deleted posts with negative scores. Outside of that, I don’t see any reason you should have been question-banned.